# Visual studio sp1 error: DACFramework_enu.msi is unavailable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install the sp1 for visual studio 2010. The first time I installed it sp1 worked fine. Then I installed the windows phone developer tools later.

Visual studio tells me sp1 was partially installed. Then when I try to re-apply sp1, it gives me this message:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework
Insert the 'Microsoft SQL Server R2 Data-Tier Application Framework' disk and click OK
```

So I downloaded the above feature from this website https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24000, and attempted to point the installer to the msi file, but I'm getting the error message:

```
The file 'DACFramework.msi' is not a valid installation package for the product Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework.  Try to find the installation package 'DACFramework_enu.msi' in a folder from which you can install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework.
```

The problem is that I had originally installed the above Data-Tier framework using the web installer, so how do I give it access to this disk?  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that while I had installed Visual Studio 2010 via the Microsoft web installer, I had actually downloaded the Sp1 ISO file, and found the required file there.